# can't synchronize Velodyne points with other PointCloud2 data

Tags: ros, synchronization, ros-kinetic, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am new to ROS and I need a help for time synchronization.
When I synchronize Velodyne points with ZED Images, they are synchronized without any problem (I attached this working code below). But, when I synchronize Velodyne points with other PointCloud2 data which is published by a node that I created, the callback function in my code never get called.
I think both have the same type of time header since they both are PointCloud2 but I don't know why the time synchronizer doesn't work in this case. I tried to use Approximate/Exact but none of them works.
Please advise.

**Working code.**

```
ros::Publisher data1_pub;

ros::Publisher data2_pub;

void callback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& data1, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& data2)
{
  ROS_INFO("Sync_Callback");

  data1_pub.publish(data1);
  
 data2_pub.publish(data2);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)

{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "TimeSynchronizer");

  std::string data1_topic = "/zed/right/image_rect_color";
 
  std::string data2_topic = "/velodyne_points";
  
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
 
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> data1_sub(nh, data1_topic, 1000);
  
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> data2_sub(nh, data2_topic, 1000);
  
  data1_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("/synchronized" + data1_topic, 1000);
  
  data2_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/synchronized" + data2_topic, 1000);
  
  TimeSynchronizer<Image, PointCloud2> sync(data1_sub, data2_sub,10);
  
   sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));

  ros::spin();

  return 0;

}
```

**Not Working code.**

```
ros::Publisher data1_pub;

ros::Publisher data2_pub;

void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& data1, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& data2)
{

  ROS_INFO("Sync_Callback");

  data1_pub.publish(data1);
  
  data2_pub.publish(data2);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)

{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "TimeSynchronizer");

  std::string data1_topic = "/velodyne_points";
 
  std::string data2_topic = "/chatter";
  
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
 
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> data1_sub(nh, data1_topic, 1000);
  
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> data2_sub(nh, data2_topic, 1000);
  
  data1_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/synchronized" + data1_topic, 1000);
  
  data2_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/synchronized" + data2_topic, 1000);
  
  TimeSynchronizer<PointCloud2, PointCloud2> sync(data1_sub, data2_sub,10);
  
   sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

**"talker" node which publishes PointCloud2 data to /chatter topic**

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){

    ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

    ros::NodeHandle n;

        ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("chatter", 1000);
    
        ros::Rate loop_rate(30); 

        int speed = 100;

    int count = 0;

    while (ros::ok()){

                sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 msg;

                msg.height = speed;

                ROS_INFO("%d",msg.height);
      
        chatter_pub.publish(msg);

                ros::spinOnce(); 

        loop_rate.sleep();

        ++count;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304795/can%27t-synchronize-velodyne-points-with-other-pointcloud2-data/) by [roskinetic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37867/roskinetic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2018-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The time synchronization uses the header timestamp to find pairs of messages. Make sure to set the header timestamp in your talker node.

```
msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
```

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2018-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roskinetic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37867/roskinetic/) on 2018-10-04**:
Thank you! It works now.